# Packet data in wireshark not highlighted on click using my custom dissector

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am writing a dissector in Lua for a custom, binary protocol. I have defined three field types:

```
f.field1= ProtoField.bytes("myproto.field1","Field 1",base.HEX)
f.field2= ProtoField.uint16("myproto.field2","Field 2",base.HEX)
f.field3= ProtoField.bytes("myproto.field3","Field 3",base.HEX)
```

These fields are added to tree like this:

```
subtree:add(f.field1,buf(offset,4))
offset = offset +4
val2=buf(offset,2):uint()
-- some logic around populating f2_description omitted
offset=offset+2
subtree:add(f.field2,val2):append_text(" (" ..f2_description ..")")
subtree:add(f.field3,buf(offset,2))
```

Now, when I open Wireshark and click on Field1 or Field3 in dissected packet's tree, I see that the selected data is highlighted in the raw packet hex view (bottom most panel):
[image: field selection is highlighted]

, but it is not the case for Field2:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A helpful chap for ask.wireshark.org had an answer: http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/8982/packet-data-in-wireshark-not-highlighted-on-click-using-my-custom-dissector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark dissectors do select the right fields if the second parameter to the tree:add(..,..) is (or at least, *directly* references) a UserData type value..

On your example, buf() is UserData, but val2 is not.

Give this a try:

```
subtree:add(f.field2,buf(offset,2):uint()):append_text(" (" ..f2_description ..")")
```

On the other hand, you wouldn't be writing a dissector for ISO8583, would you?